# How do I assign a method to a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eval

How do I assign a method to a variable? For example, I want to interpolate an object's class into a string and eval that string into a variable:

Doing this allows me to use three lines rather than multiple case statements. But I get routing errors.

So I want to reduce this:

```
        case section.class
        when MultiTextBlock
            link_to 'Edit', edit_organization_bulletin_multi_text_block_path(organization, bulletin, section), class: 'fancybox-reload', title: 'Edit this section'
        when SingleTextBlock
            link_to 'Edit', edit_organization_bulletin_single_text_block_path(organization, bulletin, section), class: 'fancybox-reload', title: 'Edit this section'
        when Calendar
            link_to 'Edit', edit_organization_bulletin_calendar_path(organization, bulletin, section), class: 'fancybox-reload', title: 'Edit this section'
        when BulletinInsert
            link_to 'Edit', edit_organization_bulletin_bulletin_insert_path(organization, bulletin, section), class: 'fancybox-reload', title: 'Edit this section'
    end
```

to something like this:

```
        edit_method = eval "edit_organization_bulletin_#{section.class.to_s.titleize.downcase.gsub(' ', '_')}_path"
        link_to 'Edit', edit_method(organization, bulletin, section), class: 'fancybox-reload', title: 'Edit this section'
```

Comment: Perhaps it would bring in more answers if you explained what you wish to accomplish from doing this.

Comment: What you are doing here is not what you are requesting and my_method is simply a String in this case. You could accomplish this with a Proc or lambda but i would not recommend it and debugging will become extremely painful in the future using this methodology. Please explain how you would handle this with case statements instead as neither form seems appropriate.

Comment: How do I add vars to the method call? I can add them to the eval statement but I'm trying to avoid that, it seems to miss the point.

Comment: "use three lines rather than multiple case statements". Write for long-term readability and to reduce maintenance. Reducing the lines of code simply to reduce them doesn't necessary result in better code, especially if it takes longer to figure out what it's doing, instead that usually results in bugs being introduced. There's an important difference between "elegant" and "terse" and sometimes more is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `send` method

```
send(method_name, arg1, arg2)
```

Also, you can use it on any object:

```
nil.send(:nil?)
```

By the way, Rails provides the convenient `underscore` method:

```
object.class.name.underscore
```

But there is another approach which I find more appropriate and less bug-inducing:

```
url_for({action: :edit, controller: object.class.name.underscore}.merge(options))
```

Comment: I like this, it makes sense, but how do I add the other vars for the correct path (organization, bulletin)?

Comment: Please notice merging with `options` at the end of line. You can add additional parameters to that hash, e.g. `merge(page: 2, organization: 'foo')`

Comment: So I've got:

`url_for({action: :edit, controller: section.class.name.underscore}.merge(organization: organization, bulletin: bulletin))`

which I'm assuming will mimic the

`link_to edit_organization_bulletin_section_path(organization, bulletin, section)`

but I still get a routing error...

Comment: Honestly, I don't know exactly its behavior in nested routes. I suggest you to play a bit with it in Rails console to find out the right way to do the thing. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

#### One way

This way seems to do what you're trying to do in your example code, even though it doesn't really involve "assigning a method to a variable"

```
snake_case_klass = object.class.to_s.titleize.downcase.gsub(' ', '_')
send "edit_#{snake_case_klass}_path", *arguments
```

#### another way

This way is similar, and really does "assign a method to a variable".

```
snake_case_klass = object.class.to_s.titleize.downcase.gsub(' ', '_')
method = self.method("edit_#{snake_case_klass}_path".to_sym)
method.call(*arguments)
```

#### but....

...most people will tell you what you're trying to do is going to wind up really confusing and probably isn't a good idea, even though Rails does this kind of thing all the time itself; it's where many of us learned to hate it from.

#### There are other other ways, depending on what you're really doing.

I don't entirely understand what you're trying to do. But you're trying to do some kind of different logic depending on class. The ordinary way to do this in OO code, especially if all those classes involved are *your* local classes, is plain old polymorphism.

```
class Something
  def special_method
  end
end

class Other
   def special_method
   end
end

# my_thing might be Something or Other, but just:
my_thing.special_method
#... and the implementation from Something or Other will be called, because that's OO.
```

If you don't control the classes itself, there are all sorts of other approaches, from decorators, to a Hash of lambdas or procs, that would let you avoid a case statement based on class without doing that dynamic method name thing. It just depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do something like this

```
snake_case_klass = object.class.to_s.underscore
send "edit_#{snake_case_klass}_path", variables
```

You may need to splat variables (`*variables`)

Why not do

```
edit_polymorphic_path(variables)
```

Answer (score 0):

This merely answers the question, "how do I assign a variable to a method?".

**Case 1: method is static (not created dynamically)**

Just convert the method name to a string or symbol and save that to a variable. To use it, use [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-send) with optional arguments and/or a block. For example:

```
m = :each_with_object
[1,2,3].send(m, []) { |e,a| a << e**2 }
  #=> [1, 4, 9]
```

**Case 1: method is created dynamically**

In this case, assign the method object to a variable. To use it, bind it to the receiver with [UnboudMethod#bind](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-bind) and invoke it with [Method#call](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Method.html#method-i-call) with optional arguments and/or a block. For example:

```
m = Enumerable.instance_method(:each_with_object)
m.bind([1,2,3]).call([]) { |e,a| a << e**2 }
  #=> [1, 4, 9]
```